# Embedded PHP vs full PHP

Tags: php, html, web-applications

Which method is more efficient in terms of server loads and page responsiveness:

- Embedding PHP in HTML
- Completely generating HTML from PHP

I'm a rookie developer and regardless of project size and spec I like generating all of my HTML from PHP classes and functions but would like to know what is the standard in this respect.

Comment: "I like generating all of my HTML from PHP classes" - can you give an example of that? If you are trapping large amounts of HTML in `echo` statements, that will get unmanageable very quickly. The most maintainable approach is to use a template library of some kind. Don't worry about speed - micro-optimisations of this kind won't make much difference.

Comment: In term of responsiveness? Doesn't matter. Load time? Embedded. The best way? MVC. Question? Opinion-based.

Comment: That's not what generates "load" when building HTML with PHP. The reason you don't mix up PHP and HTML like that is so that the business logic and presentation layers of your applications are decoupled, leading to better readability and maintainability. Has nothing to do with performance.

Comment: Have a look at Twig for example. It is a template engine that helps keep PHP and HTML seperate as they should be.

Comment: Discussing template engines would lead to a lot of _opinions_ too. PHP itself is a pretty decent template engine, as long as you have the discipline to stick to _templating_ inside the templates, not perform DB queries there. More "dedicated" template engines like good old Smarty _force_ you to keep things clean and safe.

Comment: @halfer First I include a page class that builds most of my page structure aside from content via construct and destruct methods by .= building up and echoing variables(eg: $header, $musthead, $mainMenu, $footer  etc.) Content than is similarly generated, mostly on same php file, after calling and executing page class.

Comment: @user3134700, yep, don't do it like that - it'll turn into a mess. Use a templating library. Add PlatesPHP to your list of libraries to review.

Comment: @halfer Just red a couple of hundred pages n MVC, exactly what I've been missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With new computers and processors there is almost no difference in speed. The problem is only how easy is to change the templates without changing code. For that MVC is good, but its not the only one (MVV*, MVW, MVP, MVC and so on - your choice).

There was some historical and PHP related speed differences.  Simple HTML `<html>` is faster than parsing `<?php echo '<html>'; ?>` which is even faster than `<?php echo "<html>"; ?>`

First is just send to the client, second is echoed, and fird is parsed before echoing it. http://php.net/types.string for more information.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I've only just started looking in to MVC and sure I'll find my style once more familiar it and other patterns. Just wanted to make sure I'm not gimping my current work too much by the practice. Thanks again guys.

Comment: **"Simple HTML <html> is faster than parsing <?php echo '<html>'; ?> which is even faster than <?php echo "<html>"; ?>"** - I don't think so. I'm pretty sure in modern php's all three will compile to the same opcode.

Comment: Maybe, but still it takes a while for making that opcodes. therefore for clean html its obvious - just clean - pass to browser.  For single quotes - almost the same (how ever php interpreter is working - this takes just a little time) and then once more for double quoted you have one php machine working and another parsing of it for the string between double quotes. So as you see - the code AFTER parsing might be the same - but the process of making that opcodes takes a while.